# Toggle button doesn't work at the first time on Android

Tags: javascript, android, toggle

I wrote an Android app with toggle button but toggle button does not work well at the first time. But after unchecking, if you try again, it is working properly after that.

I listed below my codes.

Which codes I have to add to activate it for the first time?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private ToggleButton togg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    togg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    }
public void nameOfMethod(View v){

    togg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (togg.isChecked()) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Servise bağlanılıyor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bağlantı sonlandırılıyor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

in .xml file:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="nameOfMethod"
    android:textOn="Bağlantıyı bitir"
    android:textOff="Bağlantıyı başlat" />
```

EDIT: It works just fine like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private ToggleButton togg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    togg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    togg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (togg.isChecked()) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Servise bağlanılıyor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bağlantı sonlandırılıyor...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

with moving setOnClickListener method to onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) and deleting android:OnClick method in .xml file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set checked status for the toggle button in xml or in your code.

Xml

```
android:checked="true"
```

Or code:

```
togg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
togg.setChecked(true);
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
togg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

instead of OnClickListener().

It will be ok if you still want to use OnClickListener, but remember to put it it onCreate instead of putting it in nameOfMethod.  (Or remember call nameOfMethod in onCreate)

To put it onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    togg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    togg.setChecked(false);
    togg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Toggle button is the button that you can switch its status between checked/unchecked, right?  Do you mean that you want it first as unchecked? Then just setChecked(false)?

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that you're setting your click listener AFTER the toggle button is selected the first time, which explains the behavior you're getting.

Move the code to set your listener outside of nameOfMethod() and it should work.

EDIT: Sorry If I wasn't clear, just remove the setOnClickListener method from your nameOfMethod(). nameOfMethod() is what will be called each time the toggle button is selected, so it really makes no sense to set a listener each time it's touched..that is why you're getting  such unusual behavior.

Instead, in your nameOfMethod(), just go right ahead and set up your conditions based on the state of the toggleButton

```
if(toggleButton.isSelected()){

  ..........

{

else

.......
```

Comment: what did you mean exactly with "move"?

Can you show the right ordered exapmle?